# Dynamodb ttl checking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I have a table called `user_state`. I have ttl with expiry and a stream trigger function. My question is when an item is being deleted from the table because of ttl expiry, will it trigger the stream function as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any items deleted in DynamoDB for any reason, will be published to connected stream.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html) is the supporting documentation.

> You can back up, or otherwise process, items that are deleted by Time
> to Live (TTL) by enabling Amazon DynamoDB Streams on the table and
> processing the streams records of the expired items.